# How to deploy Winforms application with Entity Framework and localdb .mdf file

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, deployment

Here are the steps to produce my problem.

1. Using Visual Studio, start a new project and create a new Windows forms application.
2. Add datagridview to the form
3. Add service-based database `.mdf` file localdb (v12), and create table with some data
4. Add ADO .NET Entity Data Model to access data in the `.mdf` file
5. On event Form1_load I filled the gridview by using Entity Framework like this:

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       using (TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities() ) 
       {
           dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Customers.ToList();
       }
   }
   ```

Until now, everything is ok and the application is running well on the development PC.

But when trying to deploy the application to another PC using ClickOnce or InstallShield, I get an error about connection string.

How can I fix this error?

Here is the `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TestDBEntities" 
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TestDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'"  
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

and here is the error message

[image]

I installed .Net framework 4, and `SqlLocalDB.msi` on the target PC, but the problem still appears, please help